# What causes oil in radiator of a 2012 Dodge Ram 1500 Express 5.7 l hemi

Tags: ram, water-pump, oil-in-coolant

My radiator has a milky brown to tan oily appearance I was told it’s caused by a cracked water pump. I cannot find anything that says that is possible

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It sounds more like oil is getting into the coolant to me. Maybe a crack in a head gasket?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the water pump, it's a blown head gasket.  You can prove it to yourself by using [this test kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RS3N98V).

Comment: Not sure how you can call this out as a blown head gasket? There aren't any oil passages going up through the head gasket which can cause oil to get into the water. Blown head gaskets usually exhibit water getting into the oil.